# Bash looping through and hashing values in a script

Tags: google-sheets, hash, sha256

Have ~600 words. Have a Google Sheet in which the ~600 words are both in the columns (something like B1:AV1) and the rows (something like A2:A640). All of the middle concatenates the word of the row, a space, and the word of the column. A simple example of what it would look like if it was 4x:

[image: Just an example image of what this would look like]

I'm trying to get a SHA-256 sum of each combination of words so I can find what two words went into a final value that I have (and am trying to match a combo to).

A friend told me the best way to go about this would be to download the spreadsheet and then use a bash script to iterate through each element of the sheet and return the combination of words if/when it finds the hash sum that corresponds to the one I am trying to match it with.

Please assist!

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't specify which language so I choose python which I'm most familiar and the libaries are great.

You can do the following:

```py
import itertools
import hashlib

words = ["the","quick","brown","fox"]

all_permutations = [p for p in itertools.product(words, repeat=2)]

# The hash is calculated from the both words joined with a space e.g. 'brown fox'
hashes = {hashlib.sha256(" ".join(permutation).encode('utf-8')).hexdigest():permutation for permutation in all_permutations}

hash_to_look_for = 'fb565eb6a7d52f851e9c3ffdcf2ff1b78fff40b6f5afeb8efa4be231ba987409'

print(hashes[hash_to_look_for])
```

Which generate the Output:

```
('quick', 'fox')
```

How does it work:

1. Specify the list of words `words = ["the","quick","brown","fox"]` Of course you can also generate this list of words from a file there are enough "How-To" available on the internet/Stackoverflow
2. Generate all Permutation (which is basically your nxn table). `all_permutations = [p for p in itertools.product(words, repeat=2)]`
3. Generate a key-value store (dictionary) with the key the hash and the value the permutation: `hashes = {hashlib.sha256(" ".join(permutation).encode('utf-8')).hexdigest():permutation for permutation in all_permutations}`
    Basically you have a Dictionary with following entries: `{'9324c764e9cd717efd7c30d439dc0ce9cf7ecff6b6b00a67eb24676ba3bc34ba': ('the', 'the')` in total nxn times (in the example 16 entries)
4. I specify the hash we are looking for: `hash_to_look_for = 'fb565eb6a7d52f851e9c3ffdcf2ff1b78fff40b6f5afeb8efa4be231ba987409'`
5. Since the hash is always the key in our dictionary we can easily print it with this command: `hashes[hash_to_look_for]` and get the desired permutation which generate this hash.